# Penalty function $f(a, b)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ which adds a high positive penalty only when both $a, b$ are very small

Tags: mathematical-modeling, bayesian, regularization

I'm doing Bayesian recruitment curve fitting where my curve has two parameters $a$ and $b$. Both $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I have put a Truncated Normal prior on $a$ and a Half Normal prior on $b$. I'm not modeling the covariance on these two parameters.

I want to enforce a regularization penalty that only discourages small $a$ when $b$ is very small.

Basically, I'm looking for a penalty function $f(a, b)$ for $a, b$ which adds a very high positive penalty when both $a, b$ are very small.

Could you please help find such a function?

For instance, let's say I had another parameter $c \in \mathbb{R}$ with a Gaussian prior, and suppose I wanted to discourage negative values for $c$, I would use a penalty function $f(a) = |a| - a$. (see attached figure)[image]

Since the penalty function that I'm looking for is of two variables, I'm having a hard time coming up with it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{a + b}$ or $\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2}$ or $\frac{1}{f(a, b)}$ where $f(a, b)$ is any function that tends to $\infty$ as $(a, b)$ tends to $(0, 0)$?

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll try these.